# Difference between two template code patterns where in one case a number is assigned whereas in the other the keyword typename is used

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

In the following code, what is the difference between the following two template lines.

> ```
> >      1. template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, int> = 0> 
> >      2. template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
> ```

Both the above lines are  working fine, I just wanted to know the advantages/disadvantage in using one over the other.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, int> = 0>

//template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>


int onlyOnInt(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
int main()
{
    onlyOnInt(1, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both working fine, if you write a single function.

But when you want two alternative functions, this way

```
template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_integral_v<T>>>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }

template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_integral_v<T>>>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "isn\'t integral" << std::endl; }
```

you get a compilation error where this way

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "isn\'t integral" << std::endl; }
```

works.

The reason?

Consider you're playing with SFINAE, that is Substitution Failure Is Not An Error.

The point is Substitution.

The first way, when you call

```
foo(0)
```

the substitution bring to

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }

template <typename T, typename>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "isn\'t integral" << std::endl; }
```

that is... you have two functions with the same signatures (a default template argument doesn't change the signature of a function) and a collision calling it.

In the second way you have only

```
template <typename T, int = 0>
void foo (T const &)
 { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
```

because the substitution failure in the second function make the function unusable and it's discarded. So you have only a function available and no collision.

Comment: Clear explanation